# Numpy recarray sort of columns and stack

Tags: python, numpy, pytables

relatively new to python so excuse me if this has an obvious answer that I havent found.

I am reading some temporaly contiguous binary files into numpy record arrays with the end goal of storing them in a pytable.  The problem I anticipate is that the files may not all have the same fields, or the same field order.  I have been looking for a numpy function that will sort the columns (NOT the rows) of a recarray using either the field labels or an index.  Even better would be a function that does this for you - and accounts for missing columns - when you append a recarray to another.  Below is a sample of what I had in mind:

```
#-------script------------
Myarray1 = np.array([(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3)], {'names': ('a','b','c'), 'formats': ('f4', 'f4', 'f4')})
Myarray2 = np.array([(2,1,4,3),(2,1,4,3),(2,1,4,3)], {'names': ('b','a','d','c'), 'formats': ('f4', 'f4', 'f4', 'f4')})
Myarray3 = SomeColumnSortFunction(Myarray2, sortorder=[2,1,4,3])
Myarray4 = SomeBetterVerticalStackFunction(Myarray1,Myarray2)
#
print(Myarray1)
print()
print(Myarray2)
print()
print(Myarray3)
print()
print(Myarray4)

#---------- Wished for Output -------------
[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0) (1.0, 2.0, 3.0) (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)],
 dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', 'i4'), ('c', 'i4')]

[(2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0) (2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0) (2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 3.0)],
dtype=[('b', 'i4'), ('a', 'i4'), ('d', 'i4'), ('c', 'i4')]


[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)] 
dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', 'i4'), ('c', 'i4'), ('d', 'i4')]

[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, NaN) (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, NaN) (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, NaN),
 (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0) (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)] 
dtype=[('a', 'i4'), ('b', 'i4'), ('c', 'i4'), ('d', 'i4')]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you want to reorder the fields of your structured array, just use fancy indexing:

  ```
  MyArray3 = MyArray2[['a','b','c','d']]
  ```

  If you want to use integers to sort your fields, you can use something like:

  ```
  order = [1,0,3,2]
  names = MyArray2.dtype.names
  MyArray3 = MyArray2[[names[i] for i in order]]
  ```

  (in your `sortorder=[2,1,4,3]`, you probably forgot that the first index of an iterable is 0...)
- For stacking structured arrays, have a look to the `numpy.lib.recfunctions` submodule, the `stack_arrays` function in particular. Note that you have to use `import numpy.lib.recfunctions` explicitly

Here's the docstring

```
stack_arrays(arrays, defaults=None, usemask=True, asrecarray=False, autoconvert=False)

Superposes arrays fields by fields

Parameters
----------
seqarrays : array or sequence
    Sequence of input arrays.
defaults : dictionary, optional
    Dictionary mapping field names to the corresponding default values.
usemask : {True, False}, optional
    Whether to return a MaskedArray (or MaskedRecords is `asrecarray==True`)
    or a ndarray.
asrecarray : {False, True}, optional
    Whether to return a recarray (or MaskedRecords if `usemask==True`) or
    just a flexible-type ndarray.
autoconvert : {False, True}, optional
    Whether automatically cast the type of the field to the maximum.

Examples
--------
>>> from numpy.lib import recfunctions as rfn
>>> x = np.array([1, 2,])
>>> rfn.stack_arrays(x) is x
True
>>> z = np.array([('A', 1), ('B', 2)], dtype=[('A', '|S3'), ('B', float)])
>>> zz = np.array([('a', 10., 100.), ('b', 20., 200.), ('c', 30., 300.)],
...   dtype=[('A', '|S3'), ('B', float), ('C', float)])
>>> test = rfn.stack_arrays((z,zz))
>>> test
masked_array(data = [('A', 1.0, --) ('B', 2.0, --) ('a', 10.0, 100.0) ('b', 20.0, 200.0)
 ('c', 30.0, 300.0)],
             mask = [(False, False, True) (False, False, True) (False, False, False)
 (False, False, False) (False, False, False)],
       fill_value = ('N/A', 1e+20, 1e+20),
            dtype = [('A', '|S3'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that the answer by [@PierreGM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228506/277826) doesn't seem to work in older versions of `numpy`, for instance this snippet:

```
  python -c 'import numpy as np
from pprint import pformat
print np.__version__
a = np.array([ (1, 4.0, "Hello"), 
               (-1, -1.0, "World")],
       dtype=[("f0", ">i4"), ("f1", ">f4"), ("S2", "|S10")])
print("a : "+ pformat( a ) )
print("a1: "+ pformat( a[["f0", "S2"]] ) )
print("a2: "+ pformat( a[["S2", "f0"]] ) )
'
```

... produces this for me (python 2.7):

```
1.5.1
a : array([(1, 4.0, 'Hello'), (-1, -1.0, 'World')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '>i4'), ('f1', '>f4'), ('S2', '|S10')])
a1: array([(1, 'Hello'), (-1, 'World')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '>i4'), ('S2', '|S10')])
a2: array([(1, 'Hello'), (-1, 'World')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '>i4'), ('S2', '|S10')])
```

... which is to say, columns are not rearranged at all.

---

EDIT: found an alternative, using [numpy.lib.recfunctions](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.lib.recfunctions.html); also [Indexing — NumPy v1.5 Manual (NumPy Reference)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [Structured arrays (aka “Record arrays”) — NumPy v1.5 Manual (NumPy User Guide)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.5.x/user/basics.rec.html). Basically:

- create a new list, containing the rearranged column dtypes in the order that you want
- create a new list of `np.array`s via `.view` (so that both name and dtype are preserved for each) that represent each column, reordered according to the rearranged column dtype list
- Use the list of `np.array`s as argument to `numpy.lib.recfunctions.merge_arrays`

So this can be added to the previous snippet in this post:

```python
from numpy.lib import recfunctions as rfn

rdtype=[("S2", "|S10"), ("f1", ">f4"), ("f0", ">i4")]
#ra = np.array( [ np.array(a[rdt[0]], rdt) for rdt in rdtype] )
#print [np.array(a[rdt[0]], dtype=rdt) for rdt in rdtype] # no
#print [np.array(a[rdt[0]]) for rdt in rdtype] #passes, no field names
print [np.array(a[rdt[0]]).view([rdt]) for rdt in rdtype] #ok
ra = rfn.merge_arrays( ( [np.array(a[rdt[0]]).view([rdt]) for rdt in rdtype] ) )
print("a4: "+ pformat( ra ) )
```

... which additionally outputs:

```
[array([('Hello',), ('World',)], 
      dtype=[('S2', '|S10')]), array([(4.0,), (-1.0,)], 
      dtype=[('f1', '>f4')]), array([(1,), (-1,)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '>i4')])]

a4: array([('Hello', 4.0, 1), ('World', -1.0, -1)], 
      dtype=[('S2', '|S10'), ('f1', '>f4'), ('f0', '>i4')])
```

... which finally shows that columns are rearranged as demanded.

Well, hope this helps someone - hopefully there's nothing else to go wrong here,
Cheers!